# Launch tests normally when not in debug mode

Tags: c++, makefile, gdb

For my C++ project  have the following `Makefile`:

```
GDB=gdb
DEBUG ?= 1
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    CCFLAGS =-DDEBUG
    RUNPATH =${GDB}
else
    CCFLAGS=-DNDEBUG
    RUNPATH="/bin/sh -c"
endif

CPP=g++ ${CCFLAGS}
TESTGEN=cxxtestgen
CFLAGS_DBG=""
TEST_BUILD_PATH="./build/tests"
BUILD_PATH="./build"
TESTS_SRC_PATH="./tests"
SRC_PATH=""

# NORMAL TARGETS
# To Be filled

# RUN TESTS

test_command_parser_gen:
    ${TESTGEN} --error-printer -o ${TESTS_SRC_PATH}/CommandParser/runner.cpp  ./tests/CommandParser/testCommandParser.h

test_command_parser_build: test_command_parser_gen
    ${CPP} -o ${TEST_BUILD_PATH}/commandParser ${TESTS_SRC_PATH}/CommandParser/runner.cpp ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp

test_command_parser_run: test_command_parser_build
    ${RUNPATH} ./build/tests/commandParser

clean:
    find ./build ! -name '.gitkeep' -type f -exec rm -f {} + && find ./tests ! -name *.h -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

When I launch the tests via the command:

```
make test_command_parser_run
```

As expected the `gdb` fires up and I can use it to debug the test. But sometimes I need just to run the test as is (eg. when in CI) therefore I use the following command to do so:

```
make test_command_parser_run DEBUG=0
```

But in that case I get the following error:

```
cxxtestgen --error-printer -o "./tests"/CommandParser/runner.cpp  ./tests/CommandParser/testCommandParser.h
g++ -DNDEBUG -o "./build/tests"/commandParser "./tests"/CommandParser/runner.cpp ./src/tools/command_parser.cpp
"/bin/sh -c" ./build/tests/commandParser
/bin/sh: 1: /bin/sh -c: not found
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'test_command_parser_run' failed
make: *** [test_command_parser_run] Error 127
```

Therefore, I wanted to know how I can tell the make to execute the test without `gdb` when **not** in "debug" mode.

The whole idea behind this is somehow automatically debug my application without the need to remember the command and the compilation sequence to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove quotes around `/bin/sh -c`, like so:

```
else
  CCFLAGS=-DNDEBUG
  RUNPATH=/bin/sh -c
```